# Notice: Undefined offset: 14 in user_node_load() (line 3682 of modules/user/user.module)

Tags: users

I'm getting the following error:

Notice: Undefined offset: 14 in user_node_load() (line 3682 of modules/user/user.module).

What fields in the db do I need to alter to fix this?
I've tried "users" table, creating new admin and altering the UUID to 1 as I thought this would fix it, but no.

Can anyone offer any advice of how to fix this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're either trying to load node 14 or user 14 and that doesn't exist.

Comment: I see. Node 14 exists and it appears to be loading fine. Is that user ID 14? thanks Colin.

Comment: Without seeing your system I have no idea, but you mention you have been fiddling in the database and I suspect that one or more nodes have authors that don't exist anymore.

Answer (score -1):

This happened when you exported the content to another installation and viewed the content - the new install was looking for the same user id that created the content on the original site.

Solution - 
 Create a new user and update author in corresponding node.